# Redis Socket Connect Intermittent

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Intermittently we are getting connection exception from Redis. It generally occurs once in 100 times.I am sharing Exception logs

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unknown reply: 2
redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:71)
redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:122)
redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getBinaryMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:189)
redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.zrange(BinaryJedis.java:1465)
com.moglix.ecom.es.api.service.impl.APICacheManager.deleteBrandFromCache(APICacheManager.java:775)
com.moglix.ecom.es.api.service.impl.APICacheManager.removeBrandsFromCacheByName(APICacheManager.java:766)
com.moglix.ecom.es.api.service.impl.APICacheManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$948a485d.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:652)
com.moglix.ecom.es.api.service.impl.APICacheManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1b2c303d.removeBrandsFromCacheByName(<generated>)
com.moglix.ecom.es.api.cache.APICacheController.clearBrandsFromCacheByName(APICacheController.java:170)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5700.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: I checked that there are 102 clients at that time and we have created 2k clients from config

Comment: is there on one else Geeks of @redis to provide suggestion?